# System.IO.IOException: The file exists

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am trying to deploy crystal reports project with asp.net C#, using visual studio 2017. The whole project is running fine on localhost but when try to open crystal report page then following error show it. when i run website from visual studio 2017, crystal report load successfully. Can any one tell how to publish or deploy website with crystal report?

Server Error in '/' Application.

The file exists.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The file exists.

```
[IOException: The file exists.
]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +10842741
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError() +22
   System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost) +127
   System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() +9
   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) +1140
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) +653
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions options) +92
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportOptions options, HttpResponse response, Boolean asAttachment, String attachmentName) +96
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType formatType, HttpResponse response, Boolean asAttachment, String attachmentName) +118
   VT_CMS.Reports.frmAcademicReportviewer.OpenExaminationGraphSWReport() in E:\VT_CMS\VT_CMS\VT_CMS\Reports\Global\frmAcademicReportviewer.aspx.cs:4467
   VT_CMS.Reports.frmAcademicReportviewer.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\VT_CMS\VT_CMS\VT_CMS\Reports\Global\frmAcademicReportviewer.aspx.cs:228
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

removed temp data from windows/temp
```